# C - accessing parameter inside the function

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

I have a `main.c` file

```
int boyut(const char* string);

char greeting[6] = {"Helle"};
int main(){
    greeting[5] = 0x00;
    int a = boyut(greeting);
    return 0;
}

int boyut(const char* string){
    int len=0;
    while(string[len]){
        len++;
    }
    return len;
}
```

I compile it with `GCC` command `gcc -Wall -m32 -nostdlib main.c -o main.o`
When I check disassembly, I see the variable `greeting` is placed in `.data` segment. And before calling `boyut` it's not pushed into stack. Inside the `boyut` function, it acts like variable `greeting` is in stack segment. So that variable actually not being accessed inside the function. Why is it generating a code like this? How can I correct this?

```
Disassembly of section .text:

080480f8 <main>:
 80480f8:   55                      push   ebp
 80480f9:   89 e5                   mov    ebp,esp
 80480fb:   83 ec 18                sub    esp,0x18
 80480fe:   c6 05 05 a0 04 08 00    mov    BYTE PTR ds:0x804a005,0x0
 8048105:   83 ec 0c                sub    esp,0xc
 8048108:   68 00 a0 04 08          push   0x804a000
 804810d:   e8 0d 00 00 00          call   804811f <boyut>
 8048112:   83 c4 10                add    esp,0x10
 8048115:   89 45 f4                mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc],eax
 8048118:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
 804811d:   c9                      leave  
 804811e:   c3                      ret    

0804811f <boyut>:
 804811f:   55                      push   ebp
 8048120:   89 e5                   mov    ebp,esp
 8048122:   83 ec 10                sub    esp,0x10
 8048125:   c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4],0x0
 804812c:   eb 04                   jmp    8048132 <boyut+0x13>
 804812e:   83 45 fc 01             add    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4],0x1
 8048132:   8b 55 fc                mov    edx,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4]
 8048135:   8b 45 08                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]
 8048138:   01 d0                   add    eax,edx
 804813a:   0f b6 00                movzx  eax,BYTE PTR [eax]
 804813d:   84 c0                   test   al,al
 804813f:   75 ed                   jne    804812e <boyut+0xf>
 8048141:   8b 45 fc                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4]
 8048144:   c9                      leave  
 8048145:   c3                      ret    

main.o:     file format elf32-i386

Contents of section .data:
 804a000 48656c6c 6500                        Helle.
```

Comment: Compile with `gcc -Wall -m32 -O1 -fverbose-asm -S main.c` then look into the generated `main.s` assembler file

Comment: And study the ABI specification for your system

Comment: `push   0x804a000` <= this seems to pushing the address of `greeting`. Of course, if you examine the `.o` file, you shouldn't forget that you still need linking (and thus symbol relocation) to take place. I would think you should actually see a placeholder `push $0x0`.

Comment: @dhke yes you are right. thank you! that should be the answer

Answer (score 0):

The function `boyut` is declared like this:

```
int boyut(const char* string);
```

That means: `boyut` takes a pointer to `char` and returns an `int`. And indeed, the compiler pushes a point to `char` on the stack. This pointer points to the beginning of `greeting`. This happens, because in C, an array is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element under most circumstances.

If you want to pass an array to a function so it is copied to the function, you have to wrap the array into a structure and pass that.